# file_get_contents from url and explode using php

Tags: php

I want to extract the number 2,673 from the following part of a webpage

```
<ul class="instructor__stats">


<li>
    <div class="small">
        Students
    </div>
    <div class="a2">
        2,673
    </div>
</li>




<li>
    <div class="small">
        Courses
    </div>
    <div class="a2">
        1
    </div>
</li>
```

And I use this PHP code:

```
    <?php        
    $url = file_get_contents("https://www.udemy.com/user/54a6106b68452/");


        $pageArray = explode('<ul class="instructor__stats">


<li>
    <div class="small">
        ', $url);

        if (sizeof ($pageArray) >1){

            $pageArray_2 = explode('
    </div>
</li>




<li>
    <div class="small">
        Courses', $pageArray[1]);

            $numberofstudents = $pageArray_2[0];   
        }
?>
```

It doesn't return anything. I know that I'm accessing the page and getting the content because I extracted some pure text for testing. Any idea how I can extract the number 2673? The number 2673 updating daily so that value is coming from somewhere else too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://somesite/somepage"));
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
echo $xpath->query("//div[@class='a2']")[0]->textContent;
```

---

The most important part is the `$xpath->query`:
We try to find a `div` with class `a2`, the first match `[0]` and extract its text (`->textContent`).Finally, we use `trim()` to remove any extra spaces.